# how to properly adjust XML hierarchy of nodes

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to create a xml file by using html form. i am able to create a xml file ... but while some hirarchy come that time it is giving error. please check my code or update it. below is output which i want.

```html
output :-<url>TODO</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>TODO</name>
            <connection>TODO</connection>
        </license>
    </licenses>
```

php code:-

```html
$text5 = htmlentities($_POST['tb5']);
$text6 = htmlentities($_POST['tb6']);
$text7 = htmlentities($_POST['tb7']);


$xmlns = 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$project = $document
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'project'));
$project->setAttributeNS(
  
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',  
  'xsi:schemaLocation',
  'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'
);

$project
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'url'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text5));


$project
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'licenses')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'license')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'url')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text6));
   ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'name')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text7));
 

$document->save("d.xml");

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If i will remove last 2 line  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'name')) 
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text7)); then xml is genrated but i also want last 2 lines also.

Comment: Error i am getting this --->Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: mind the semicolon in `->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text6));`

Comment: You may wish to slightly re-word the question, since although you had a syntax error, other users may benefit from seeing how to properly adjust XML hierarchy of nodes (semantics) which was the real crux of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code, after creating a text node - as well as needing a semantic change to your DOM hierarchy.  Here's your corrected code correcting appendChild to $project.

```
<?php

$text5 = htmlentities($_POST['tb5']);
$text6 = htmlentities($_POST['tb6']);
$text7 = htmlentities($_POST['tb7']);

$xmlns = 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$project = $document
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'project'));
$project->setAttributeNS(

  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  'xsi:schemaLocation',
  'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'
);

$project
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'url'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text5));


$license = $project
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'licenses'))
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'license')) ;

$license
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'name'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text6));

$license
  ->appendChild($document->createElementNS($xmlns, 'connection'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text7));

$document->save("d.xml");

?>
```

**EDIT**: I modified the script a little to match your XML output format specified.  You were creating a second url node, but not the proper name/connection node.  Those are now in place.

Comment: :-i want  'url' and 'name' inside licenses and license. in your solution only url is inside. name is outside

Comment: I modified my answer to add name and connection inside license.  I did NOT put url inside, since in your example XML it is outside.  Let me know if this is the format you are looking for now, or update your question's XML sample output and I'll match it.